# Add program to search path in Bash

Tags: macos, bash, path, command, symlink

I'm trying to add a program into the search path that Bash uses to find commands and I can't get that to work. I'm specifically trying to add `ant` but I'd like to know more generally if this is possible.

Here's what I've done:

1. Downloaded and extracted `apache-ant-1.9.3`
2. Put that in `~/bin/ant`

   ~/bin/ant--> ls

   apache-ant-1.9.3
3. Created a symlink in `/usr/local/bin` that refers to `~/bin/ant`

   /usr/local/bin--> ls -l

   lrwxr-xr-x  1 BobMarley  admin     38 Feb  7 09:36 ant -> ../../../Users/BobMarley/bin/ant/
4. `/usr/local/bin` is already in my `PATH` variable
5. Made sure all the permissions are in order

..and the result I get is -bash: ant: command not found.

I know I could just add ~/bin/ant to my path to begin with but I don't want to add any more crap to `PATH`. I'd much prefer to just drop programs into the search path and be done with it. Is this possible and if so, what am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: provide `which ant`, make sure that `/usr/local/bin` is in your PATH. Why don't you put the `ant` file into `/usr/local/bin`, and make the siylink to it?

Comment: `which ant` returns nothing because it can't find `ant` to begin with. As I said above, `/usr/local/bin` is in my PATH already. I'm not sure I'd want to move the `ant` executable out of its current directory because I suspect it needs files around it to run properly.

Comment: Modifying your local environment's `PATH` seems far cleaner than polluting `/usr/local/bin` with symlinks to your personal files. Why not just install `ant` in `/usr/local/` for real?

Comment: Crap, you know what, my symlink points to a directory containing the `ant` executable, it doesn't point directly to the `ant` executable. I corrected that and it works now. I don't get why it didn't search the subdirectories of `~/bin/ant` though. It seems to search the subdirectories of dirs you add to your PATH.

Comment: Forgive me, how would I "install" ant in /usr/local? Is that just a matter of dropping the extracted apache-ant-1.9.3 dir in there? Because I did try that and I couldn't get Bash to find ant.

Comment: @Headache install ant into `/usr/local` in the same matter as to `bin/` but of `sudo`

Comment: @Headache: No, it doesn't search subdirectories of directories in `$PATH`, just the directories themselves. And I'd make the symlink point to an absolute path rather than a relative path: `ant -> /Users/BobMarley/bin/ant` without the `./../..`. Depending on your filesystem organization, `/usr/local/bin/..` might not point to `/usr/local`, and so on for `../..` and so forth.

Comment: @KeithThompson Why wouldn't `/usr/local/bin/..` not point to `/usr/local` ?

Comment: If `/usr/local/bin` is a symlink to `/foo/bar/bin`, then `/usr/local/bin/..` would resolve to `/foo/bar`.